# Ansible templates with undefined variables

Tags: linux, loops, automation, ansible

I have a file with variables that I use in my playbook:

```
net_interfaces:
  ...
  - name: "eth0"
    ip: "192.168.1.100"
    mask: "255.255.255.0"
    gateway: "192.168.1.1"
  ...
```

and I want to deploy some configs with this variables, for example *ifcfg-eth0*:

```
DEVICE={{ item.name }}
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR={{ item.ip }}
NETMASK={{ item.netmask }}
GATEWAY={{ item.gateway }}
```

but sometimes there is no **gateway** variable for **item** and in this case I want to remove string

```
GATEWAY={{ item.gateway }}
```

from this config file on the target machine. How can I achieve this without creating another task for a certain hosts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add condition:

```
{% if item.gateway is defined %}
GATEWAY={{ item.gateway }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe you can tell me how to make one-line if-condition in this case? I've tried `{{ '--gateway={{ item.gateway }}' if item.gateway is defined }}` but I've got exactly this string in output: _--gateway={{ item.gateway }}_

Comment: Found the only one way: `{% if item.gateway is defined %}GATEWAY={{ item.gateway }}{% endif %}`

Comment: You can use -%} instead of %} to suppress the newline in the output, so it would still be a single line in the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

Another (and better) way is to use 'default' filter because in this case we can check if some variable was defined and set it's default value if it wasn't. Example:

```
{{ my_string_value | default("awesome") }}
```